# combining two tables and sum Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science

I have a database of a company that deals with compensation payments. I have to. I'm working on three tables:
Conclusions, m_email and m_lead. In the "conclusion" table I have, among others: id and creation date. In the m_email table I have: id, how many were opened, how many clicks. In the m_lead table: id, conclusion_id, creation_date.
I need to check the following:
1. Divide the year into four parts and check how many applications were from January to April, from April to July etc.
2. Next I need to attach a table to get something like that. E.g:

```
ID = 1      
number_of_aplications = 5000     
number_of_leads = 7000
```

Below I have placed my code. I have two problems:
1. I do not know how to add months to have one result from three months.
2. I do not know how to connect the number of leads to this code

```
select date_part('month', creating_date) as "1-3", count(id) as 
"Number of applications"
from applications
where date_part('month', creating_date) between  '01' and '03' AND
date_part('year', creating_date) between '2017' and '2018'
group by  date_part('month', creating_date)
order by count(id) DESC ;
```

Comment: May I ask, to be sure to answer correctly to your request, what is the table application and how it is linked to your model (that is composed of 'conclusion', 'm_email' and 'm_lead')?

Comment: No. 
No. These are only conclusions from January, February and March. In addition to the number of conclusion, I would like to have the number of leads assigned to these months.
ps. sorry for my English

Comment: I have this: ID = 1. Month = 1 number_of_applications = 10000. However, I want this in the row  : ID = 1.     Month = 1.    number_of applications = 10000 number_of_leads = 11000

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your demand is a little hard to understand for me. But for the first part of your problem I think I can answer :

**Initial situation**

You have a table 'applications(id int primary key, creation_date timestamp)'

**What you need (for my understanding)**

Have the number of application per trimester (January to March and so on)

**A possible solution**

```
select a.delta, sum(applicationByMonth) as applicationByMonth, sum(leadByMonth) as leadByMonth
from 
(
    select '1 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as applicationByMonth
    from applications
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) <= 3
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '2 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as applicationByMonth
    from applications
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 4 and 6
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '3 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as applicationByMonth
    from applications
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 7 and 9
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '4 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as applicationByMonth
    from applications
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 10 and 12
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
) as a
inner join 
(
    select '1 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as leadByMonth
    from m_lead
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) <= 3
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '2 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as leadByMonth
    from m_lead
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 4 and 6
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '3 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as leadByMonth
    from m_lead
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 7 and 9
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
    union
    select '4 trimester' as delta, cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) as month, count(id) as leadByMonth
    from m_lead
    where cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int) between 10 and 12
    group by cast(date_part('month', creation_date) as int)
) as l 
    on a.delta = l.delta
group by a.delta
order by 1;
```

I think you can adapt to fit exactly your needs from there.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you! The goal is to measure the effectiveness of the campaign. Some campaigns generated a large number of leads, which resulted in a small number of applications = high costs. I want to find periods of time that gave such a result, eg "1 trimester" gave 40,000 applications from 50,000 leads. like your code + additional column with leads.
In the m_lead table I have: ID, id_application, creating_date.

I also have the m_lead_campaign table: id, id_lead, id_campaign. That sounds good, but the number of campaigns was huge and I do not know what can be done about it.

Comment: Is there any table that have an id of campaign and an id of application?

Comment: One table is not. But I have two tables connected by a relation:
m_lead: id, id_of_application, creating_date

The second table is m_lead_campaign: id, id_lead, id_of_application

Comment: I haven't seen it previously ;) I correct my answer as soon as I can ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)